# Assign each horizontal border of the table an id

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use JavaScript to dynamically create a table. In the picture below, You can see there are 5 horizontal borders. I want to assign each horizontal border an id. For instance, I want to assign the the top border an id of 0; the second top border an id of 1, etc. The code that I wrote is actually assigning the id of each row which is not what I want. When I run my code, I can see the second row shakes rather than the second horizontal border shakes. Basically, I want to create 5 horizontal lines and assign each line a id. Maybe creating a table to get 5 lines is a overkill.  Hope someone could help me out. Thank you in advance.

[image]

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="code.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="code_js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

/* css: */

```
.deco {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        var tr = document.createElement('tr');   
        var td1 = document.createElement('td');
        tr.appendChild(td1);
        table.appendChild(tr);
        td1.id = i;// id placed
        td1.className = "deco";
    }
    document.body.append(table);
    $('#' + 1).effect("shake");

});
```

Comment: move the two `appendChild`s below the `td1.className = "deco";"` line

Comment: You can not assign an `id` to a `border`, a border is a style property of an element, not an element itself (to which you can assign ids). If you are trying to achieve a "shaking border" you can try playing around with the `<hr />` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, creating a table just for drawing horizontal lines is an overkill. You can use `<hr>` tag instead. Just like you have created 5 rows in a table, create 5 `<hr`. Also, you won't need any CSS decoration.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var hr = document.createElement('hr');
    hr.id = "hr" + i;
    document.body.append(hr);
  }
  $('#hr' + 1).effect("shake");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Shaking line</h1>
</body>

</html>
```